# ASP.NET WebForms TreeView Nodes As Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, treeview

How can I create ASP.NET TreeView nodes as Table from C#? Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could bind the Treeview's datasource to a Gridview, Listview, or Repeater.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new in ASP.NET. Can you explain with more details?

Comment: Sure. Did I understand correctly that you already have a Treeview but you want to display a table? If so, you already have data that populates the Treeview, which might be a datatable, xml, collection. etc. My suggestion was to use that data to populate the table. There are various ASP.NET controls that can display a table. [Here is an example using a Gridview[(http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Dynamically-create-DataTable-and-bind-to-GridView-in-ASPNet.aspx)

If you already have your data you don't need to dynamically create it like he does in the article.